# MINE (noun) used in a compound noun such as 'mine-captain' & 'mine-worker'

Tags: compound-nouns

[Mine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mine) is widely used as a possessive-pronoun, it is also used as a noun and a verb.

There can be a compound noun like **gold-mine** containing '**mine**'; there could also be compound nouns which start with '**mine**'. For example: '[mine-captain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mine_captain)' & '[mine-worker](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mineworker)'.

1. Could ***mine-worker*** also be referred to as **miner**?
2. Is there a word for ***mine-captain*** other than just **captain** (which I think would be better)?
3. Are there any other compound nouns which start with **mine**?
4. Why ***mine-captain*** and not ***mining-captain***; and ***mine-worker*** and not ***mining-worker***?

Comment: The possessive-pronoun ***mine*** *(belonging to me)* has nothing to do with ***mine = pit / excavation*** - which forms *many* compound words *(mineshaft, minehead, minefield, minesweeper...)*. But I don't understand what exactly you're asking here - or ***why***.

Comment: I mentioned that MINE is also used as a possessive-pronoun just to clarify that MINE in mine-worker is not used mistakenly instead of MY. I am interested in MINE which is used as a NOUN and a VERB. Since it is a noun too, there might have some compound nouns which contain that noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine-worker is another term for miner, yes. There may be subtler shades of meaning but that's about it.

Mine-captain doesn't seem to be as common as "mine captain", and isn't used in all regional varieties of English. I'm not quite clear exactly what the job is, so it might be the same as is called "foreman" in British mining.

You could probably coin an awful lot of compounds with this sense of "mine", but I couldn't say how many are attested without doing research that you could do yourself just as easily.

As to 4, why does English use words with Germanic roots for some things and French roots for others? Actually, we know why for some of those, but I hope it illustrates the point. For that matter, why do we have the word "window" which does not resemble the word with the same meaning in neighbouring related languages? When terms are coined, there is not always a good reason why someone chose one over another. As a word gradually becomes generally accepted, there my be any reason, or no apparent reason, why one new term gains traction more than another.

Comment: I wonder if there were any interesting compounds besides 'mine-captain' & 'mine-worker' ^^